# Structuring services in a middleware pattern like in rack and wsgi

Tags: angularjs

I have various angular services which call a rest api on the server.

If the user is not authenticated then the server always returns a map - {authenticated: false}, otherwise it returns the expected data.

I would like to create a middleware function which always intercepts the return value. It then sets the $route based on the result. If the user not authenticated then redirects him to a cer 
tain route.

How do I do it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Angular's $http service has responseInterceptors which is probably what you are looking for.

Have a look at the official documentation here :

http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.$http

under the **Response interceptors** section.

Also another tutorial that explains the response interceptors can be found here.

http://bl.ocks.org/3410406

Hope this helps.

Comment: Response interceptors have since been deprecated https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/ad4336f9359a073e272930f8f9bcd36587a8648f and replaced with interceptors

Answer (score 0):

[angular-http-auth](https://github.com/witoldsz/angular-http-auth) is already built to do what you are trying to accomplish in AngularJS